# Prometheus AlertManager Slack Alert URL does not resolve

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

In Prometheus AlertManager’s slack notifications, the default title includes a clickable URL that goes to: http://alertmanager-main-0:9093/#/alerts?receiver='.
We are using Kube-Prometheus on Kubernetes.
How do I configure http://alertmanager-main-0:9093 so that it will resolve?
I have read that it can be resolved by configuring web.external-url. But I haven’t found any docs to help out with where to set it and what to set it to.
Does it need any DNS settings?

Also, in AlertManager UI (NodeIP:NodePort/#/alerts…), clicking on the ‘Source’ of the alerts lands to a page ‘http://prometheus-k8s-0:9090/graph' which doesn’t resolve. It seems like a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

You should modify the pod arguments and add --web.external-url={{your public url}} to both prometheus and alert manager.

Comment: thank you for this. Most answers tell you to do this in Prometheus but they do not mention it has to be done in Alert Manager as well!